# How to initialize maps inside interfaces in java

Tags: java, java-8, interface, hashmap

I want to initialize a hashmap inside an nested interface. I have tried doing smtng like

```
interface constants{
    .........
    .........
    interface anotherInterface{
        ........
        ........
        Map<String, HttpMethod> API_METHOD = new HashMap<String,HttpMethod>();
        API_METHOD.put(POST, HttpMethod.POST);
    }
}
```

but this is givin error "Cannot resolve symbol 'put'".
can someone please tell me the reason for this and some other way to initialize the map.

**Note:** I don't want to initialize my map like and i am using java 8

```
new HashMap<String, HttpMethod>() {
        {
            put(POST, HttpMethod.POST);
          
        }
    };
```

Comment: Could you add current implementation? more code will help more to understand

Comment: current implementation? I didn't get it. like it is just an interface inside and interface where i want to initailize this.

Comment: Have you tried a static initialization block?

Comment: you can use static/default method as per your requirement

Answer (score 2):

Any 'field' in an interface immediately becomes a `public static final` one, therefore, making a **mutable** field is an incredibly bad idea - that's making global state, the thing just about every style guide out there lists as number one on the list of 'bad ideas'.

But, you're trying to 'initialize it', so I think your intent is that this map is itself 'constant' (it has a bunch of key/value mappings and can no longer be changed).

You have a few options.

### You don't have many k/v pairs

```
Map<String, HttpMethod> API_METHOD = Map.of(
  "POST", HttpMethod.POST,
  "GET", HttpMethod.GET);
```

### You have a lot of k/v pairs

Use the guava (a.k.a. google collections) library.

Then you can do:

```java
Map<String, HttpMethod> API_METHOD = ImmutableMap.<String, HttpMethod>builder()
  .put("POST", HttpMethod.POST)
  .put("GET", HttpMethod.GET)
  .build();
```

### You have a lot and do not want to use guava

Now it gets a little mad, especially without java 11. You can write a static method in a *class* (which can be private if you want), and then call that static method from your interface:

```
public interface MyInterface {
  Map<String, HttpMethod> httpMethods = MyInterfaceUtil.makeHttpMethodMap();
}

class MyInterfaceUtil {
  static Map<String, HttpMethod> makeHttpMethodMap() {
    Map<String, HttpMethod> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("POST", HttpMethod.POST);
    return Collections.unmodifiableMap(map);
  }
}
```

Note:

- That util class can be in the same file, but you should not make it `public`.
- `Collections.unmodifiableMap` is very important.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification I used the guava library. Since I am using java 8 so I don't think that I can use the Map.of (tell me if I am wrong here).

Comment: Yup, `Map.of` is.. 9, I think? Later than 8, certainly. That very last option (with the utility class) will work on 8. But if you're happy with guava, that's great - it's certainly the shorter, easier to read code here :)

Comment: For a single mapping like in the question, you can use `Collections.singletonMap(POST, HttpMethod.POST)`. Since Java 2. By the way, Java 9’s immutable maps work for an arbitrary number of mappings too. If you have more than ten, you have to use `Map.ofEntries(Map.entry(key1, value1), Map.entry(key2, value2), Map.entry(key3, value3), Map.entry(key4, value4), …)` There is no need for Java 11 for using a helper method. Since Java 9, you can have a `private static` method in the interface.